# Diagnosing netlogo extension command error

Tags: netlogo

When I try to execute the first-n-integers extension example:

show noise:first-n-integers 5

I receive an error "ERROR: Expected command. " in the console or in the code tab.
I have mostly copied and pasted the class examples as is, just renaming them and putting them in a different package.  I wish the error was a little more descriptive, as I suspect I am making a simple error somewhere.

I'm using 5.0.4 without the JRE and a 1.7.0_45 JRE/JDK on a x64 Windows 7 machine.

My manifest.txt file with fully-qualified class-manager and crlf at the end of the version line--

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Extension-Name: noise
Class-Manager: org.xyz.extensions.NoiseExtension
NetLogo-Extension-API-Version: 5.0  <--there is a crlf here
```

the jar is in a subfolder with my model file

```
test/
  test.nlogo
  noise/
    noise.jar
```

This is my Class-Manager:

```
package org.xyz.extensions;

import org.nlogo.api.*;

public class NoiseExtension extends DefaultClassManager {
  public void load(PrimitiveManager primitiveManager) {
    primitiveManager.addPrimitive(
      "first-n-integers", new org.xyz.extensions.NoiseGenerator());
  }
}
```

This is the NoiseGenerator file:

```
package org.xyz.extensions;
import org.nlogo.api.*;

public class NoiseGenerator extends DefaultReporter {

public Syntax getSyntax() {
    return Syntax.reporterSyntax(
    new int[] {Syntax.NumberType()}, Syntax.ListType());

}

public Object report(Argument args[], Context context) throws ExtensionException {
// create a NetLogo list for the result
LogoListBuilder list = new LogoListBuilder();
int n ;
// use typesafe helper method from
// org.nlogo.api.Argument to access argument
try {
  n = args[0].getIntValue(); 
}
catch(LogoException e) {
  throw new ExtensionException( e.getMessage() ) ;
}
if (n < 0) {
// signals a NetLogo runtime error to the modeler
throw new ExtensionException
  ("input must be positive");
}
// populate the list. note that we use Double objects; NetLogo
// numbers are always Doubles
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
  list.add(Double.valueOf(i));
}
return list.toLogoList();
```

}
}

Thanks for any help.

AJB

Answer (score 1):

This was asked and answered here:

https://groups.google.com/d/msg/netlogo-devel/eIq8drflsc8/7y_Ooh6R0sgJ

The answer was to correct the spelling of `getSynax` to `getSyntax`.